# getting error : chromedriver installation failed error eacces permission denied mkdir

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, selenium-chromedriver, node-modules

When I tried to install Chrome driver `npm install chromedriver --chromedriver-force-download` with node js, I am getting this error: `chromedriver installation failed error eacces permission denied mkdir`.

I have applied full permission of `777` and I'm still getting this error, can anyone please help me why I'm getting this error?

I used these commands:

```
1) npm i chromedriver

2) Force Download : npm install chromedriver --chromedriver-force-download
```

Comment: https://github.com/gdotdesign/elm-github-install/issues/21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out using the `sudo` keyword

```
 1)sudo npm i chromedriver

2) Force Download :sudo npm install chromedriver --chromedriver-force-download
```

Answer (score 5):

This one works for me on Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo npm -g install chromedriver --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```